# Angular5 http best practices

Tags: angular, rest, typescript, observable, angular5

I'm building some applications (yes, more than one) with Angular 5.
I'm trying to follow all of Angular dos and don'ts

But I can't understand a couple things

> 1) Difference between this...

```
this._http.get<User>(this._ubiRest.servicesUrls.getUser)
```

> ...and this

```
this._http.get(this._ubiRest.servicesUrls.getUser)
```

If anyway I have to do use the **map** method to cast to type User (or maybe I don't??)

> 2) In a service would be better to do this...

```
getUserData(): Observable<User> {

        return new Observable((observable) => {

            if (!!this._loggedUser) {
                observable.next(this._loggedUser);
                observable.complete();
            }
            else {
                this._http.get(this._ubiRest.servicesUrls.getUser)
                    .map(this._extractData)
                    .subscribe(user => {
                        this._loggedUser = user;
                        observable.next(user);
                        observable.complete();
                    }, this._handleError);
            }

        })
    }
```

> ...or this?

```
getUserDataX(): Observable<User> {
    if (!!this._loggedUser) {
        return new Observable(observable => {
            observable.next(this._loggedUser);
            observable.complete();
        });
    }
    else {
        return this._http.get<User>(this._ubiRest.servicesUrls.getUser)
           .map(this._extractData)
           .catch(this._handleError);
    }
}
```

Comment: see this https://sergeome.com/blog/2017/11/26/simply-about-new-httpclient-in-angular/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with estus answer is that it doesn't work if you have a "Finally" operator on the other side, so what worked for me was this:

```
getUserData(): Observable<User> {
      return new Observable(observable => {
            if (!!this._loggedUser) {
                observable.next(this._loggedUser);
                observable.complete();
            }
            else {
                this._http.get<User>(this._ubiRest.servicesUrls.getUser)
                    .retry(2)
                    .map(this._mapUserResponse)
                    .subscribe(x => {
                        console.log("getUserData", x);
                        observable.next(x);
                        observable.complete();
                    }, error => {
                        console.warn("LoggedUserService error: ", error);
                        this._ubiFunctions.showSnackBar({
                            message: error.statusText
                        });
                        observable.error(error);
                    })
            }
      });
}

private _mapUserResponse(rawResponse: User) {
    this._loggedUser = rawResponse;
    return this._loggedUser;
}
```

my-component.ts

```
myGetUserData():void{
        this._progressDialog.openProgress();
        this._loggedUser.getUserData()["finally"](() => {
             this._progressDialog.closeProgress();
        }).subscribe(data => {
            this.user = data;
            this._router.navigate(['/home']);
            this._ubiFunctions.showSnackBar({
                message: "Utente caricato correttamente"
             });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A 'best practice' is to use Angular 4 `HttpClient` instead of Angular 2 `Http`. And the code in OP looks like it's `HttpClient`, not `Http`.

> Difference between this...
>
> If anyway I have to do use the map method to cast to type User

The point of generic method is that generic parameter type is used somewhere internally. Here it affects the type of observable:

```
this._http.get<User>(this._ubiRest.servicesUrls.getUser)
.map(user => { /* user has User type */ })
```

This can be clearly seen in [`HttpClient` API](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get); `get(...)` returns `Observable<any>` and `get<T>(...)` returns `Observable<T>`.

> In a service would be better to do this...

None of the above. `new Observable(observable => { ... })` is observable constructor antipattern, a counterpart to promise constructor antipattern. It is:

```
   if (!!this._loggedUser) {
        return Observable.of(this._loggedUser);
    }
    else {
        return this._http.get<User>(this._ubiRest.servicesUrls.getUser)
       .map(this._extractData)
       .catch(this._handleError);
    }
```

Comment: Did you read the question? I use angular 5 and of course I use the HttpClient service

Comment: I read it, and it clearly says `Angular2 http best practices`. To be honest, downvoting your own answers isn't the best way to get help.

Comment: It's pretty obvious that "Angular2" is meant to distinguish from AngularJs and the very first line in the question says "I'm building some Angular5 Apps". And to be honest, saying that to be honest downvoting isn't the best way to get help, doesn't encourage me to upvote you....

Comment: This wasn't an encouragement. This may be obvious to you but not to any other user who isn't proficient in mind reading. `Http` exists and is being used in Angular 5, and there's no mention of `HttpClient` in the question.

Comment: @Tony Samperei we are not on facebook or twitter. If the answer is helpful we must press 'upvote'.

Comment: Okok. Upvoted and selected. Everybody happy?
Thanks to Estus, because the "Observable.of" is very handy.

Comment: @TonySamperi No problem. I'm not sure what you mean about `finally`. Returned observable should be usable with any operators, as long as they are imported. That would be a pain to wrap observables with `new Observable(...)` every time (that's why it was called antipattern).

Comment: the finally operator fires after either successful or fail callbacks in the subscribe...
I know that using "new Observable" everywhere may be an anti-pattern, but it's not my fault if the $q.defer of AngularJs(which, btw I loved) doesn't exist anymore...

Comment: @TonySamperi Yes, I would expect the code in the answer to behave exactly same way with `finally` as the one you've posted. [$q.defer was considered antipattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-Anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern) too, for a good reason, in 99% cases it's possible to replace it with less clumsy promise chain. As for your case, I usually switch from observables to promises and async/await at this point (a completed observable with single value), because async/await is tidier, and observables are unable to provide additional benefits here.

Comment: I think promise is not compatible with Internet Explorer and unfortunately I need my apps to be runnable on IE11. I'll take a look to async/await

Comment: @TonySamperi A lot of things that are used in Angular apps aren't compatible with IE, the framework itself heavily uses ES6 features such Promise and Map. It's expected that the app is used with polyfills (e.g. core-js), and Promise is surely polyfillable,